# What are evolutionary algorithms for topology and weights evolving of ANN (TWEANN) other than NEAT?

Tags: neural-networks, training, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, neuroevolution

I wonder, if there are other than NEAT approaches to evolving architectures and weights of artificial neural networks?

To be more specific: I am looking for projects/frameworks/libraries that use evolutionary/genetic algorithms to simultanousely evolve both topology and train weights of ANNs other than NEAT approach. By 'other' I mean similar to NEAT but not based entirely on NEAT. I hope to find different approaches to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article on neuroevolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution) contains a list of neuroevolution techniques (e.g. NEAT). I will list below the examples that evolve both the parameters and the topology of the neural network.

- [Cellular encoding](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.5939&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1994)
- [GNARL](http://demo.cs.brandeis.edu/papers/ieeenn.pdf) (1994)
- [EPNet](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axk/evoNN2.pdf) (1997)
- [Evolutionary acquisition of neural topologies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220516089_Evolutionary_reinforcement_learning_of_artificial_neural_networks) (2007)
- [Interactively constrained neuro-evolution](https://repositorium.ub.uni-osnabrueck.de/handle/urn:nbn:de:gbv:700-2012101710370) (2012)
- [Deus ex neural network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.5892.pdf) (2012)
- [Spectrum-diverse unified neuroevolution architecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.06703.pdf) (2017)
- [Covariance matrix adaptation with hypervolume sorted adaptive grid algorithm](http://eprints.bournemouth.ac.uk/26161/7/HAGA_SWEVO.pdf) (2017)

Comment: I would like to note that I am not familiar with any of these methods. This list is based on the info in the mentioned Wikipedia article.